# Unit tests failing to run on TestClass defined class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper

I have a test class:

```
[TestClass]
class DocumentStoreProviderTests : TestBase
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory(Unit)]
    public void DocumentProvider_AssertEntityToCreateIsValid_Fail_When_DocumentNameIsEmpty()
    {
        // arrange
        var scope = new DefaultScope();
        var invalidUpdateEntity = Builder<Dom.Document>
            .CreateNew()
            .With(x => x.Name, string.Empty)
            .Build();

        //act
        Action methodUnderTest = () => scope.InstanceUnderTest.AssertEntityToCreateIsValidAsync(invalidUpdateEntity).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        //Assert
        methodUnderTest.ShouldThrow<BusinessValidationException>();
    }
}
```

However I am getting this when I try to run the tests:

```
========== Discover test finished: 1090 found (0:00:02.8716539) ==========
No tests found to run.
```

I am using resharper to run the unit tests and all of my other test files run fine.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What happens when you remove the TestCategory decorator? Does it work then?

Comment: @Dudemanword Same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the classes DocumentStoreProviderTests and TestBase  as public.

Answer (score 0):

TestCategory ("Unit") should fix it.  It matches a string that is the name of the category.